# Debian Squeeze upgrade and SSH lockout

Tags: ssh, debian-squeeze

I've just did a "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade" on my Debian 6 server, restarted the virtual machine and now I'm locked out. SSH connection closes immediately after login. I have no physical access to the server. Any ideas?

Here is SSH debug log:

```
~$ ssh -vvv MY_USER_NAME@MY_WEBSITE.com -p 11337
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to MY_WEBSITE.com [95.211.47.128] port 11337.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/MY_USER_NAME/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/MY_USER_NAME/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/MY_USER_NAME/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/MY_USER_NAME/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/MY_USER_NAME/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/MY_USER_NAME/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze2 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: put_host_port: [MY_WEBSITE.com]:11337
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[MY_WEBSITE.com]:11337" from file "/home/MY_USER_NAME/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/MY_USER_NAME/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 141/256
debug2: bits set: 512/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 88:0d:f5:fa:6a:2f:e7:fe:46:07:fd:cc:55:4b:76:5c
debug3: put_host_port: [95.211.47.128]:11337
debug3: put_host_port: [MY_WEBSITE.com]:11337
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[MY_WEBSITE.com]:11337" from file "/home/MY_USER_NAME/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/MY_USER_NAME/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[95.211.47.128]:11337" from file "/home/MY_USER_NAME/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/MY_USER_NAME/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '[MY_WEBSITE.com]:11337' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/MY_USER_NAME/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 509/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/MY_USER_NAME/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/MY_USER_NAME/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/MY_USER_NAME/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/MY_USER_NAME/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/MY_USER_NAME/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/MY_USER_NAME/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/MY_USER_NAME/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/MY_USER_NAME/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/MY_USER_NAME/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
MY_USER_NAME@MY_WEBSITE.com's password: 
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 58 padlen 6 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to MY_WEBSITE.com ([95.211.47.128]:11337).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AGENT_PID
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env GPG_AGENT_INFO
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_COOKIE
debug3: Ignored env GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWID
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL
debug3: Ignored env GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env SESSION_MANAGER
debug3: Ignored env USERNAME
debug3: Ignored env DEFAULTS_PATH
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_SESSION
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_KEYRING_PID
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_GB.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env GDM_LANG
debug3: Ignored env MANDATORY_PATH
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env GDMSESSION
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env LANGUAGE
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWPATH
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env COLORTERM
debug3: Ignored env XAUTHORITY
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Linux odyssea 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Sun Sep 23 10:07:46 UTC 2012 x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
You have new mail.
Last login: Wed Dec 26 18:30:29 2012 from 46.197.149.195
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-signal reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

Connection to MY_WEBSITE.com closed.
Transferred: sent 2768, received 2440 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 17435.1, received 15369.1
debug1: Exit status -1
```

Thanks.

Comment: Since the motd is getting displayed the problem is probably not with SSH.

Comment: I fear you are basically fcked

Comment: yes I noticed nginx says "file not found" when I try to open the site.
Seems like nothing is working.

Comment: Try running some command as an argument to ssh client like this: `~$ ssh -vvv MY_USER_NAME@MY_WEBSITE.com -p 11337 "/bin/ls /"`.

Answer (score 0):

You could check admin panel from your hoster and enter recovery mode there.
Looks like upgrade went really wrong. Then chroot into your server and finish upgrade.

Comment: Seems like there is no recovery mode or web console or something similar with my provider...